# update variants in a table depending on subvariants types

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update the variants in a table like the figure below:

[image: variants table]

Where each variant type is mapped to another different variant type.
for example, *red* variant type which is a  variant type from *color* variants is mapped to *L* variant type which is a variant type from *size* variants.

The variants data structured like below:

[image: variants sturcure]

I wrote this code so far, and I am stuck at this point, any help is appreciated.

```
                    {data &&data.map((variant) => (
                      <>
                        {variant.variants &&
                          variant.variants.map((subVar) => (
                            <tr
                              className="whitespace-nowrap "
                              key={subVar.id}
                            >
                              <td>
                                <input
                                  checked={selectAll}
                                  type="checkbox"
                                  className="custom-control-input"
                                />
                                <label className="custom-control-label"></label>
                              </td>

                              <td className="px-6 py-4">
                                {(() => {
                                  for (let i = 0; i < variant.id; i++) {
                                    const temp = subVar.variantName;

                                    return `${temp}`;
                                  }
                                })()}
                              </td>
```

Comment: Can you share how this data is structured?

Comment: And you're asking to update the variants like the picture bellow, but do you have a print of how it is right now?

Comment: yes, I updated the question and added the data structure. Thanks for point it out.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing how your data is structured I might think that you could use template string, like you're doing, but adding both variants, like:

```
 {data &&data.map((variant) => (
              <>
                {variant.variants &&
                  variant.variants.map((subVar) => (
                    <tr
                      className="whitespace-nowrap "
                      key={subVar.id}
                    >
                      <td>
                        <input
                          checked={selectAll}
                          type="checkbox"
                          className="custom-control-input"
                        />
                        <label className="custom-control-label"></label>
                      </td>

                      <td className="px-6 py-4">
                        {(() => {
                            let tempArray = []
                            for(let x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {
                                tempArray.push(data.variants[x])
                            }
                            return tempArray.join(' / ')
                        })()}
                      </td>
```

When you're return a single variable you don't need to use the template string, you can simply return it.

You can read more about, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but not what I want. the problem is I don't know how to loop through variants data and I want to print out each variant type and the next variant type from another variant.

Comment: Amazing, just edited my answer.

Comment: Basically, you can use the `data` length to iterate into all variants, push it into a tempArray, then use the Array.join() to join all variantNames into a single string.